# How to get a node location map within a node in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, dictionary, drupal-modules

I'd like to show node's location on a map within a node (between other fields).
Do You know any

- formatter
- CCK field
- other module-based

solution for that?

*PS I know a semi-satisfactory solution that lets display the map above or below a node, but not in between other fields: to enable a node location block and place it close to the content.*

Comment: Do you use the location cck field and want to use a formatter for that?

Comment: Yes, I use a location CCK field.
I guess, some formatter would be the most straightforward solution, but any other that works is equally fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must have missed something obvious...

[Location](http://drupal.org/project/location) + [Gmap](http://drupal.org/project/gmap) modules

and then set location CCK field display to anything with "map" in `DRUPAL_URL/admin/content/node-type/story/display`

Comment: I had this working perfectly in my Drupal 6.22 installation, but somewhere along the update path, it stopped working in the nodes display, does your setup stil show maps in the node display?

Answer (score 1):

I use the [GMAP module](http://drupal.org/project/gmap) for that. Can you check if that is a good solution for you ?

Comment: João, as far as I know, the module provides only node location in a block or a map of all node locations. It doesn't display location map within a node (what I'm looking for), does it?